# Display image url use AXIOS combine with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, axios

now im doing AXIOS code combine with laravel to get image from instagram URL. the URL is this `https://www.instagram.com/p/B_zZCRpB895/media/?size=t`

AXIOS is new from me. to get the image, i tried this simple code. i set this code into my frontend site

```
<img id="imgsrc" src="" > 

<script>
 axios
  .get('https://www.instagram.com/p/B_zZCRpB895/media/?size=t', {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  })
  .then(response => {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data, 'base64');
    document.getElementById("imgsrc").src = Buffer;
    console.log(Buffer);  
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.error(ex);
  });
</script>
```

but the image not display into `<img id="imgsrc" src="" >`

i really want that, when we open the page. the instagram image can display.

how to solve this matter. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use file reader to get base64 and set it as the image source :

```
<script>
    axios.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/B_zZCRpB895/media/?size=t', {responseType: "blob"})
        .then(function (response) {
            var reader = new window.FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(response.data);
            reader.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById("imgsrc").src = reader.result;
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry @Mohammad Mirzaee Jevinani do i able to download it? after can read the file?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you are retrieving this via an AJAX call using axios?

The endpoint you provided returns an image source already. To make it appear in the image element all you need to do is set the src to the endpoint URL as shown below. Unless you need to run a process to do something to the image you don't need to get the data as an array buffer.

```
document.getElementById("imgsrc").src = "https://www.instagram.com/p/B_zZCRpB895/media/?size=t";
```